# Не могу добавить JScrollPane для прокрутки JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

Вот часть кода:

```
super("Бухгалтерия");
setLayout(null);
JTextArea.setBounds(450, 50, 300, 460);
JTextArea.setFont(font);
JTextArea.setEditable(false);
add(JTextArea);
```

Помогите разобраться, нужно сделать так чтобы прокрутка осуществлялась вниз.
Пытался сделать так:

```
JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
getContentPane().add(jScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
ScrollPane.setViewportView(JTextArea);
```

После этого JTextArea вообще пропадает.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```
super("Бухгалтерия");
txtArea = new JTextArea();
//txtArea.setFont(font);
//txtArea.setEditable(false);

JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(txtArea);
jScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
jScrollPane.setViewportView(txtArea);
jScrollPane.setBounds(450, 50, 300, 460);
jScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(jScrollPane);

getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: к сожалению не получилось, всё равно не видно поле super("Бухгалтерия");
        setLayout(null);
        JTextArea.setBounds(280, 50, 470, 460);
        JTextArea.setFont(font);
        JTextArea.setEditable(false);
после этого вставил Ваш код, не заработало